# WooCommerce: stack shipping class costs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following setup in WooCommerce:

- Product A = Shipping Class 1
- Product B = Shipping Class 2
- Product C = Shipping Class 2
- Shipping Class 1 costs $10
- Shipping Class 2 costs $20

When a customer orders Product A, B and C, I expect the shipping costs to be $30. The question is, is that possible?

Because I have properly setup the shipping classes and products. However in the above situation only $20 shipping costs is calculated.

Is that a correct behavior of WooCommerce shipping classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, found it!

In WooCommerce you can set the shipping costs to be add 'per shipping class' by default.

So problem solved.